# Is it possible that $f$ is differentiable?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $$f=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0,0 \leq x <1\\ 
1,x=1
\end{matrix}\right.$$

This function is not continuous at $x=1$.Is it possible that $f$ is differentiable?

Comment: No since $f$ differentiable on $x_0$ imply $f$ continuous on this point

Comment: Ok..Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not at $x = 1$. Recall that for $f$ to be differentiable at a point $c$, we require that the following limit exists:
\[f'(c) = \lim \limits_{x \to c}\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c}.\]
Now, $\lim_{x\to c}(x-c)$ always does exist (it is $0$), so certainly if the above limit exists, then it is also the case that \[\lim \limits_{x\to c}(f(x) - f(c)) = \lim_{x \to c}\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c}(x-c) = f'(c)\cdot 0 = 0.\]
But that just means $\lim \limits_{x\to c}f(x) = f(c)$, which means that $f$ is continuous at $c$.

Comment: Ok..Thank you very much!!